# I wanted to verify a particular field is present & print on console using RESTAssured API Automation testing

Tags: intellij-idea, get, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I wanted to verify a particular field is present & print on console using RESTAssured API Automation testing in IntelliJ IDea. The field is in array and have multiple values.

- I wanted to print the field in console as well.
- Field name is `annualBasePay` and its value is `124917`.

I need to verify only the field `annualBasePay`

```
[
  {
    "worker": {
      "wID": "137cf520",
      "employeeID": "T19"
    },
    "workerDescription": "Tim Moore",
    "workerId": "T19",
    "userId": "T19",
    "workerType": "Employee",
    "jobRelatedInfoType": {
      "positionTitle": "Systems Architect 5",
      "manager": {
        "wID": "1b1696eabe",
        "employeeID": "T823"
      },
      "adjustedServiceDate": "1976-01-16",
      "annualBasePay": "124917",
      "annualBaseCurrency": null
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Please add sample json that contains the key `annualBasePay` and its value.

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 please find the sample json

Comment: [
    {
        "worker": {
            "wID": "137cf520",
            "employeeID": "T19"
        },
        "workerDescription": "Tim Moore",
        "workerId": "T19",
        "userId": "T19",
        "workerType": "Employee",
        "jobRelatedInfoType": {
            "positionTitle": "Systems Architect 5",
            ive",
            "manager": {
                "wID": "1b1696eabe",
                "employeeID": "T823"
            },
            "adjustedServiceDate": "1976-01-16",
            "annualBasePay": "124917",
            "annualBaseCurrency": null,
}
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose one of 2 ways:

```
given()
  ...
  .then()
  .body("jobRelatedInfoType.annualBasePay", hasItems("124917"));
```

or

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItems;

Response res = given()...;
List<String> basePays = JsonPath.with(res.asString()).get("jobRelatedInfoType.annualBasePay");
assertThat(basePays, hasItems("124917"));
```

Comment: Thanks  @lucasnguyen17 that worked and printed al the values of annualBasePay and annualBaseCurrency.

Comment: @BhavyaSriChundru please, accept my answer, thanks.